# Get routes with historical LIVE data

Tags: here-api

I would like to retrieve historical travel times from HERE API.

Following the API documentation for 'Calculate Route', I requested travel times for a fixed route at a fixed departure time for different days in the past, using `mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled`.

The result is the same route every day and a weekday pattern (i.e., same travel time each Monday) for travel times. This obviously does not include actual traffic conditions on the specified day.

From the documentation, I would have expected to get specific travel times for each day in the past (up to one year).

Did I miss something or is this just not possible?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the exact route for a past date. For any date other than NOW(current time), the route is calculated with the accumulated historical data taking into consideration the week day, time of the day, any construction work etc.